# Passing oAuth parameters in REST request

Tags: oauth

I have a spec for a project that accesses a third party remote API RESTfully and requires oAuth. The spec includes the following text:

> Access to the API requires the use of the OAuth protocol. A
>   per-organisation shared secret / access key combination prevents
>   access from unauthorised parties. Because the service endpoint
>   identifies the organisation, no other parameters are expected to be
>   passed in the OAuth header that encapsulates the REST request.

Of this, I don't fully understand the following:

> Because the service endpoint
>   identifies the organisation, no other parameters are expected to be
>   passed in the OAuth header that encapsulates the REST request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`oauth_*` parameters can be passed either in the Authorization header or as URL params. I read that quote as meaning if you pass the `oauth_*` values in the Authorization header don't include other values in the header.

OAuth params as a header:

```
 GET /initiate?foo=bar HTTP/1.1
 Host: photos.example.net
 Authorization: OAuth realm="Photos",
    oauth_consumer_key="dpf43f3p2l4k3l03",
    oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
    oauth_timestamp="137131200",
    oauth_nonce="wIjqoS",
    oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Fprinter.example.com%2Fready",
    oauth_signature="74KNZJeDHnMBp0EMJ9ZHt%2FXKycU%3D"
```

OAuth params in the URL:

```
 GET /initiate?foo=bar&oauth_consumer_key=dpf43f3p2l4k3l03&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=137131200&oauth_nonce=wIjqoS&oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Fprinter.example.com%2Fready&oauth_signature=74KNZJeDHnMBp0EMJ9ZHt%2FXKycU%3D HTTP/1.1
 Host: photos.example.net
```